# Cordova build fail

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, gradle, cordova-plugins

So I tried to install a new plugin in my (working) Ionic app, and that would be https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-dynamic-links/

I had an odd error, so I tried a few things and ultimately got back to where I was using a `git reset` to completely undo what have been done.

... But the error won't disappear.

I tried to upgrade Cordova and Ionic, to remove node_modules and `npm install` again, to remove and add back Android platform... nothing helps.

```
cordova build android
cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release: Android platform: V7+
cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release: No custom version found in config.xml - using plugin default
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Android platform: V7+
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to C:\Users\JB\Dropbox\dev\azkara\platforms\android\app\build.gradle
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to C:\Users\JB\Dropbox\dev\azkara\platforms\android\cordova-android-support-gradle-release\azkara-cordova-android-support-gradle-release.gradle
Android Studio project detected
config file res/values/facebookconnect.xml requested for changes not found at C:\Users\JB\Dropbox\dev\azkara\platforms\android\res\values\facebookconnect.xml, ignoring
config file res/values/facebookconnect.xml requested for changes not found at C:\Users\JB\Dropbox\dev\azkara\platforms\android\res\values\facebookconnect.xml, ignoring
config file res/values/facebookconnect.xml requested for changes not found at C:\Users\JB\Dropbox\dev\azkara\platforms\android\res\values\facebookconnect.xml, ignoring
cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release: Android platform: V7+
cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release: No custom version found in config.xml - using plugin default
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Android platform: V7+
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to C:\Users\JB\Dropbox\dev\azkara\platforms\android\app\build.gradle
cordova-android-support-gradle-release: Wrote custom version '27.+' to C:\Users\JB\Dropbox\dev\azkara\platforms\android\cordova-android-support-gradle-release\azkara-cordova-android-support-gradle-release.gradle
Preparing Firebase on Android
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\JB\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171
studio
:wrapper

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 0s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
publishNonDefault is deprecated and has no effect anymore. All variants are now published.
Configuration 'compile' in project ':app' is deprecated. Use 'implementation' instead.
+-----------------------------------------------------------------
| cordova-android-firebase-gradle-release: 15.+
+-----------------------------------------------------------------
+-----------------------------------------------------------------
| cordova-android-support-gradle-release: 27.+
+-----------------------------------------------------------------
The Task.leftShift(Closure) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use Task.doLast(Action) instead.
        at build_889mq4973ul5dy09k37yyn7v6.run(C:\Users\JB\Dropbox\dev\azkara\platforms\android\app\build.gradle:155)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\JB\Dropbox\dev\azkara\platforms\android\cordova-support-google-services\azkara-build.gradle' line: 16

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']
   > Cannot add extension with name 'googleServices', as there is an extension already registered with that name.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\JB\Dropbox\dev\azkara\platforms\android\cordova-support-google-services\azkara-build.gradle' line: 16

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']
   > Cannot add extension with name 'googleServices', as there is an extension already registered with that name.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess cordova.
```

I really need help understanding what the hell happens and how I can get over it.

Comment: Error showing com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin is twice.

Comment: Sure, but I don't know what plugins are using it, nor would I know how to fix this

Comment: check it added twice in build.gradle in android folder

Comment: and also check project.settings

Comment: `cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks`?

Comment: Sure, that's the first thing I did. As I said, I even reset my git and deleted platform to be sure it can't remain anything of it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, finally got it working. Removed `plugins` folder, walked my plugins list to remove unnecessary stuff, removed `node_modules` folder, removed Android platform, upgraded everything, reinstalled everything ( you can use `ionic cordova prepare` for plugins if you want, or if you removed Android platform, adding it back will fetch plugins anyway). Build.

Comment: What you said is not clear: You said you removed plugins folder, then you walked your plugins list to remove unnecessary stuff. How can you remove unnecessary stuff when you have already removed the plugins folder? Plus which unnecessary stuff did you remove? Please provide more explanations.

Comment: I removed plugins I didn't need anymore from the list in package.json so they won't be downloaded and added to the project again :)